# AWS CLI: ECS register-task-definition and the requires-compatabilies option

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, circleci, aws-fargate

I'm trying to adapt my CircleCI config file to build my node.js app to a Docker image and deploy it to AWS ECS. I started with [this config.yml](https://github.com/ricktbaker/docker-circleci-ecr-ecs/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) file from ricktbaker and I'm trying to make it work on Fargate.

When I initially ran these changes in CircleCI, I got this error:

**An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Task definition does not support launch_type FARGATE.**

It looks like I should be able to modify line 71 with the `requires-compatibilities` option to change how the task definition is registered, but I keep getting an error I can't figure out.

```
json=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --container-definitions "$task_def" --family "$FAMILY" --requires-compatibilities "FARGATE")
```

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --requires-compatibilities, FARGATE
```

Am I adding the option incorrectly? It seems to match [AWS' docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html)... **Thanks, for any tips.**

---

I tried adding the `debug` option as well, but I don't see anything particularly helpful in the log (slightly redacted, below).

```
2019-03-13 03:05:45,948 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.11.76 Python/2.7.15 Linux/4.4.0-141-generic botocore/1.5.39
2019-03-13 03:05:45,948 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['ecs', 'register-task-definition', '--container-definitions', 'MYCONTAINERDEFINITION', '--family', 'MYTASKNAME', '--debug', '--requires-compatibilities', 'FARGATE']
2019-03-13 03:05:45,948 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x7fd7e93fbb90>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,948 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x7fd7e985d398>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,949 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/service-2.json
2019-03-13 03:05:45,962 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.ecs: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x7fd7ea57ecf8>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,962 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: ecs
2019-03-13 03:05:45,963 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecs: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7fd7e9381d70>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,966 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/waiters-2.json
2019-03-13 03:05:45,967 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([(u'family', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f066d0>), (u'task-role-arn', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f06950>), (u'network-mode', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f06990>), (u'container-definitions', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f069d0>), (u'volumes', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f06a10>), (u'placement-constraints', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f06a50>)])
2019-03-13 03:05:45,967 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.register-task-definition: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x7fd7e9381140>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,968 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.register-task-definition: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x7fd7e98661b8>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,968 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.register-task-definition: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x7fd7e9402ed8>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,971 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ecs/2014-11-13/paginators-1.json
2019-03-13 03:05:45,972 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecs.register-task-definition: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x7fd7e947e320>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,972 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.register-task-definition: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f06a90>>
2019-03-13 03:05:45,972 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecs.register-task-definition: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x7fd7e8f1e890>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command line format is correct, i.e. `register-task-definition --requires-compatibilities "FARGATE"`
Since Fargate is quite new. So, you may have to make sure that `awscli` is recent version.

What is your installed `awscli` version? the latest version is `1.16.123`

And, the recommended way `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something to watch for when using `--user`: it installs `aws` in a folder in `~/.local`. Make sure then that this folder is in your `$PATH`.